# How to add custom field to wordpress header?

Tags: wordpress, header, advanced-custom-fields

I have tried plugins that allowed me to put content in the header, however the problem is I need a field so I can wrap it around divs and style it in my html. Is this possible with [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

So basically a field that can be udpated in the admin, and then is in a for each loop that echos the field name and can be wrapped in divs to style.

Comment: What the `header` has to do with this? Can you exemplify your problem with code?

Comment: @user2684452 I don't have any code. I am trying to put a custom field(s) in the header that I can update via admin.

Comment: You are required to show research efforts when asking a question, please, read the guide [ask]. There are lots of examples here and at [wordpress.se] to get you started. . . . . . Search for the keywords: ACF, `wp_header`, Settings API.

Answer (score 1):

if you can access the Theme Editor function (under Theme > Editor), there is a Header php file where you can update, put divs and styles and everything that you want there.